# How to detect JVM compiler thread

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot, jvmti

A JVMTI agent using the JNI to call Java objects [sometimes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/500) crashes the JVM with:

```
guarantee(!thread->is_Compiler_thread()) failed: cannot make java calls from the compiler
```

How can the agent best determine whether the current thread is a compiler thread in order to avoid this crash?

Comment: Erm ... why are you making calls on the current thread?  But anyway, you should be able to identify a compiler thread by its name and thread group.  For example "C2 CompilerThread1".  Of course, such code is platform specific.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C. We're using the current thread because some memory or thread resources are exhausted and we don't want to consume even more resources. Maybe that thinking is faulty, but that was the rationale. I was wondering about using thread/group names and agree it would be platform-specific and therefore perhaps a bit tricky to maintain.